# Jsf DataModel Impl That Supports Paging with JPA

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I need a **javax.faces.model.DataModel** implementation that retrieves table page elements using a JPA SELECT query as the user scrolls to a new page in the data table.
Something like **javax.faces.model.ResultSetDataModel** but it shall uses JPQL to fetch elements. Or is there a way to use **javax.faces.model.ResultSetDataModel**  in JPA environment?

Thanks

Comment: too bad it isn't primefaces, otherwise you could use this http://leonotepad.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/primefaces-datatable-lazy-loading-with.html

Comment: 2 yrs ago I've worked in company where they used richfaces and they had such a data model (mostly copied from some that they found on the web, I think on richfaces forum), so I know there is. Just don't know where it is.

Comment: We have internal datamodel class which extends `org.ajax4jsf.model.ExtendedDataModel<RecordType>`. It works fine with internal FetchList class. Any subclass of FetchList built based on SELECT query. For datamodel is used the subset for selected page. After change page or change sorting subset is rebuilt (in fetch method).

Answer (score 0):

I have an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/jsflive/mymail-owb) showing a custom `DataModel` that supports paging and selection of items. Have a look at the `SelectableDataModel` and `PageableDataModel` where the paging is done.

Those custom `DataModel` classes use a `DataProvider` to fetch the paged data from anywhere. In the example I use a `DataProvider` implementation to get data from a DB via JPA.

I created this example for a session at the JAX 2011. The [slides for this session](http://de.slideshare.net/michael_kurz/jsf-und-jpa-effizient-kombinieren-wjax-2011) are available too, but only in German.

The example is built with MyFaces 2.1.3, OpenWebBeans (CDI), Hibernate (JPA) and an in memory Derby DB.